# Embedding library and it's includes via CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm creating a very small project that depends on the following library: https://github.com/CopernicaMarketingSoftware/AMQP-CPP

I'm doing what i always do with third-party libraries: i add their git repo as a submodule, and build them along with my code:

```
option(COOL_LIBRARY_OPTION ON)
add_subdirectory(deps/cool-library)
include_directories(deps/cool-library/include)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} coollib)
```

This has worked perfectly for libraries like Bullet, GLFW and others. However, this AMQP library does quite an ugly hack. Their include directory is called `include`, but in their CMake `install()` command, they rename it to `amqpcpp`. And their main header, `deps/cool-library/amqpcpp.h`, is referencing all other headers using that "fake" directory.

What happens is: when CMake tries to compile my sources which depend on `deps/cool-library/amqpcpp.h`, it fails because it's not finding `deps/cool-library/amqpcpp/*.h`, only `deps/cool-library/include`.

Does anyone have any idea how i can fix this without having to bundle the library into my codebase?

Comment: create a symlink amqpcpp -> include

Comment: I can't modify a submodule. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how CMake is supposed to work.

CMake usually builds an entire distributive package of a library once and then installs it to some prefix path. It is then accessible for every other build process on the system by saying "find_package()". This command finds the installed distibution, and all the libs, includes etc. automagically. Whatever weird stuff library implementers did, the resulting distros are more or less alike.

So, in this case you do a lot of unnecessary work by adding includes manually. As you see it can also be unreliable.

What you can do is:

- to still have all the dependencies source distributions in submodules  (usually people don't bother doing this though)
- build and install each dependency package into another (`.gitignore`d) folder within the project  or outside by using their own `CMakeLists.txt`. Let's say with a custom build step in your `CMakeLists.txt`
- use "find_package()" in your `CMakeLists.txt` when build your application

Comment: I like the submodule workflow because, in order to build my app, it's a single cmake/make step, instead of having to build tons of other libs. This is specially useful when there are multiple platforms involved.

Comment: Well, you can still have it. Just make sure you use `find_package`. You wouldn't really want to add all the include paths manually for big packages, e.g. Qt and boost. Note that downloading and building these submodules is not always necessary, because most of the people who do computer graphics, games etc. already have Bullet, GLFW etc. packages installed on their system.You might check if a package is already installed, and if not, download it and build it from sources. Again, big packages are extremely long to build.

Comment: Also, not all sources are available via git. For example, official repo of OGRE uses Mercurial. There are unofficial mirrors though.

Answer (score 1):

Two small addition to [Drop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37151525/577603): If the library set up their install routines correctly, you can use `find_package` directly on the library's binary tree, skipping the install step. This is mostly useful when you make changes to both the library and the dependent project, as you don't have to run the `INSTALL` target everytime to make library changes available downstream.

Also, check out the [ExternalProject module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/ExternalProject.html) of CMake which is very convenient for having external dependencies being built automatically as part of your project. The general idea is that you still pull in the library's source as a submodule, but instead of using `add_subdirectory` to pull the source into your project, you use `ExternalProject_Add` to build it on its own and then just link against it from your project.